# Refresh page when clicked on link

Tags: html, browser-cache

I have the following to refresh my page when clicked on href.

```
    <a href="javascript:history.go(0)">Click to refresh the page</a>
```

I have this

```
    <meta http-equiv="no-cache">
```

in the head tag. Even then I am getting a cached copy. How can I avoid loading cached copy?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

instead of

```
javascript:history.go(0);
```

you may use

```
javascript:window.location.reload();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<a onclick="window.location.href=this">test</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `<meta>` tag, you're missing a content attribute. try this

```
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
```

You could also try

```
<a href="javascript:window.location.reload();">
```

but I'm not sure how that would work with regards to caching

Comment: didn't work... Still loading cached copy

Comment: That should be more cross-browser

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
window.location.href=window.location.href
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
   <a class="refresh_link" href="javascript:void(0)">click to Refresh the Page</a>


<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){



    $(".refresh_link").click(function(){

     location.reload();



    });

});
</script>
```

Used [jquery](http://jquery.com)

Comment: No use. Included jQuery library also

Comment: @Benny, got the refresh at least ? Try clearing your browsers cache first.