# Refresh page when active tab

Tags: html, meta, page-refresh

Currently in my page I am using this to refresh the page each minute:

```
<head>
...
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60" />
...
</head>
```

How instead, I want to refresh the page when a user presses the tab. Lets say a user has multiple tabs open in the web browser. And he uses a few minutes surfing on another tab. When he then press the tab for my website, I want the page to autorefresh, so the user don't have to do it himself to check for any updates on the page. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20783015/refresh-page-when-clicked-on-link

Comment: Note that when it's implemented the users experience can be rather unexpected and hence misleading.
He had been on your site and after coming back it disappears, is empty for a while and hopefully loads again.

Comment: you could put a javascript function onto your body tag with the onclick parameter  then have the js funtion reload the page

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov I don't want to refresh when pressing a button or link on my page, but I want my page to refresh when the user presses the tab for my website (tabs on the top of the web browser).

Comment: If I understand correctly, then the page refresh event should be triggered when switching to a tab (the tab is launched, but not active). And when the user visits this tab, the update is triggered. So?

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov Yes, that is correct. Lets say the user has 3 tabs open in the browser. Facebook, YouTube and my website. The user changes from my website to Facebook. After a few minutes the user switches back to my tab, and then I want to page to automatically refresh, so the user don't have to press F5(or press refresh button) to refresh the page.

Comment: Use @Andrea Viviani's answer. That's what you need.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you should use js and visibility API:

include this small script in your html page:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function() {
   if (document.hidden){
       console.log("Browser tab is hidden")
   } else {
       console.log("Browser tab is visible")
       location.reload();
   }
});
</script>
```

Adapted from here:
[Event for when user switches browser tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038643/event-for-when-user-switches-browser-tabs)